# MongoDB how to load two attributes of reference document using morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

How to load two attributes of reference document/entity using morphia

I have a Class Person and School like this

person class

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id private ObjectId id;
  private String name;
  @Embedded private PersonEducation schoolInfo;
}
@Embedded
public class PersonEduction {
  @Reference private School school;
  private String year;
  private String degree;
}
```

School Class

```
@Entity
public class School {
   @Id private ObjectId id;
   private String name;
   private String address;
   private String description;
}
```

How I can get id and and name fields of School in Person class
example 
When i want to person

```
Person person = datastore.find(Person.class).field("name").equals("xyz").get();
person.gerSchoolInfo();
```

Response (Not want all School class fields)

```
{school:{_id:ObjectId("4fcef3e20364a375e7631fb0"), name:"SchoolA"}, year:"1990", degree:"MBA" }
```

and If I query school where _id=ObjectId("4fcef3e20364a375e7631fb0"), I get all School fields

```
{_id:ObjectId("4fcef3e20364a375e7631fb0"), name:"xyz", address="some add", description="some desc"}
```

Comment: So you want to load an object (in this case of type School) but only load some of the fields from Mongo? Is this to avoid loading a very large/complex field?

Comment: yes to avoid loading of not required fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `@Reference` you should use

```
key<School> school;
```

and use custom query to load it.

```
datastore.createQuery(School.class).retrivedFields(true, "id","name");
```

Comment: I am looking for the answer of my spring-mongodb integration. The concept and abstraction in spring-mongodb is the same, specify which fields you want to load in "Query" object.

Answer (score 0):

To give an alternative to mtariq, replace

```
@Reference private School school;
```

with

```
private ObjectId schoolId;
```

and fetch it yourself. However since your School class is so simple I think you'd be better off using Lazy loading, so:

```
@Reference @Lazy private School school;
```

This will only load the school object when/if it is referenced.

Comment: @Lazy will load all fields of School, where as he want specific fields only.